# How can I prevent mysqldump from prepending the database name in CREATE VIEW?

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.1

When I execute the following:

```
mysqldump -u root -n mydatabase > mydatabase.sql
```

The tables are all dumped without the database name, but the views oddly get the database name prepended:

```
/*!50001 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `vfiscalperiodcombobox`*/;
/*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `vfiscalperiodcombobox`*/;
/*!50001 SET @saved_cs_client          = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50001 SET @saved_cs_results         = @@character_set_results */;
/*!50001 SET @saved_col_connection     = @@collation_connection */;
/*!50001 SET character_set_client      = utf8 */;
/*!50001 SET character_set_results     = utf8 */;
/*!50001 SET collation_connection      = utf8_general_ci */;
/*!50001 CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED */
/*!50013 DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER */
/*!50001 VIEW `mydatabase`.`vfiscalperiodcombobox` AS select `mydatabase`.`fiscalperiod`.`name` AS `text`,`mydatabase`.`fiscalperiod`.`id` AS `value` from `mydatabase`.`fiscalperiod` order by `mydatabase`.`fiscalperiod`.`start` */;
/*!50001 SET character_set_client      = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!50001 SET character_set_results     = @saved_cs_results */;
/*!50001 SET collation_connection      = @saved_col_connection */;
```

Because of this I cannot import this file into another database (without manually removing the database names from the file).

This happens with the following MariaDB version on Windows:

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.9-MariaDB, for Win32 (AMD64)
```

It does NOT happen with the following version on Debian:

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.28-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

Is this simply a bug? Or am I doing something wrong? Or is there a flag with which I can force mysqldump to never prepend the database name?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The user who asked on [How to prevent MariaDB mysqldump from prepending database name in CREATE VIEW?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/265209/how-to-prevent-mariadb-mysqldump-from-prepending-database-name-in-create-view), reported this [issue on mariadb's jira](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-22282)

It seems to have been fixed on Versions  10.3.35, 10.4.25, 10.5.16, 10.6.8, 10.7.4

Another workaround - also seen on that jira ticket - is to *monckeypatch* the SQL dump. Just to exemplify:

```bash
mysqldump --no-data DATABASE_NAME \
| sed "s/\`DATABASE_NAME\`\.//g" > DATABASE_NAME.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

They are not bug, but a feature of mysql. Just make sure you are using root or admin account.

Comment: Could you add a link to the piece of MySQL documentation where this is further explained?

Comment: Why is this "feature" implemented in one version but not the other?